# What are the rules for bumping a question?

Tags: discussion

I've let my 1st question sit for a few days with no replies. Are there any specific rules to bumping that question back to the top of the stack?

Comment: See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48578/what-can-cause-a-question-to-be-bumped

Comment: Add a bounty to the question.

Comment: The rule is "meaningful edits only". Editing it will bump it. Doing a meaningless edit just to bump it is cheating. But doing a genuine edit is ok. I'm sure you can find a reason to do a genuine edit :)

Answer (score 3):

If you are thinking about bumping the question by editing it:

- If you can meaningfully improve the post, feel free to edit it at any time.
- If you are editing just to bump, and not to improve the post, it is never OK no matter how much time passes.

If you are thinking about bumping the question by posting an answer:

- Never do that. Only use the answer box for post actually answering the question. Answers like "Does anyone know how to solve this?" are never OK.

When you gain more reputation, you will be able to [start a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) on both your own and others questions to give them more attention.

*(I took a look at [your question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/148477/suspicious-skype-ip-connection), and made a few edits - following the above policy - and if you feel that you want to revert some of mine, or add some more you are free to do that in the same spirit.)*